# Displaying embedded data in Mongo DB with Python

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo-3.x

I am working on a project with Flask and Mongo DB and I want to display some  embedded documents. I am not really getting error messages but the data is not displaying how I want it to. Currently, my documents look like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("590639009103ad05fd8555dc"), 
 "comments" : [ { "comment" : 
 "Hello World" } ], 
 "age" : 23, 
 "name" : "Mike" }
```

Now, I want to display data that will show the name and the comments that the individual said. I want something like this: Mike, says the following: 'Hello World'

My code looks like this:

```
thoughts = person.show()
for thought in thoughts: 
     print(thought["name"], "says the following:", thought["comments"])
```

where the show() method looks like this:

```
def show(self):
    thoughts = self.db.people.find()
    return thoughts
```

Now for the most part almost everything works how I want it to. When I run my code I get this: 
Mike says the following: {'comment': 'Hello World'}

What I need to do is to dig further down into the embedded document to display:

Mike, says the following: 'Hello World'

I have tried the following:

```
for thought in thoughts: 
    print(thought["name"], "says the following:", 
    thought["comments.comment"])
```

which gets me the following error message: KeyError: 'comments.comment'

I then tried the following:

```
for thought in thoughts: 
    print(thought["name"], "says the following:", thought["comments"]
    ["comment"])
```

which gives me the following error:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Thus, I am somewhat stuck how to pull out each comment. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`thought["comments"]` is a list of dicts. you want the `comment` field of the first item on the list, thus:

```
print(thought["comments"][0]["comment"])
```

Comment: That works! Thank you! I tried everything so close to that!